# Unity launcher uses generic icon for Firefox in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, unity, firefox, launcher, icons

After upgrading my distribution from 11.04 to 11.10 to 12.04 when starting a Firefox instance (from <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, not having a fixed launcher element) the icon displayed for it in the launcher and application switcher is the generic one (grey rectangle with a question mark in the middle). Why is that and how can I get the Firefox icon to display?

Comment: You are encouraged to answer and accept you own answers here. Please edit out the solution part of your question and provide it as an answer on its own. Thanks!

Comment: @maggotbrain: Will do if allowed. Posting an answer to an own question is delayed by 8 hours, accepting an own answer by 2 days. An attempt to delete the solution from above resulted in an error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching the web I found [this lead](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2081710) pointing me in the right direction. Then I did the following:

1. Lock icon to launcher (right-click on the launcher icon)
2. In a terminal execute `gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites` which displayed `['nautilus-home.desktop', '/home/<USER>/Desktop/ff.desktop']`
3. Identify relevant desktop file, in my case `/home/<USER>/Desktop/ff.desktop`
4. Have a look at the file, `less /home/<USER>/Desktop/ff.desktop` and check where `Icon*` keys point to, e.g. `Icon[en_US]=/usr/lib/firefox-10.0.2/icons/mozicon128.png`

   My problem was that these keys pointed to locations that didn't exist any more.
5. Use tab-completion to determine which Firefox directory actually exists, `ls /usr/lib/fir[TAB][TAB]`, finding `/usr/lib/firefox/`
6. Find a suitable icon in that directory `find /usr/lib/firefox/ -name "*.png"`, finding `/usr/lib/firefox/browser/icons/mozicon128.png`
7. Change **all** `Icon` pointers to the existing icon `/usr/lib/firefox/browser/icons/mozicon128.png`
8. Close and restart Firefox, now with a Firefox icon in the launcher and application switcher

Answer (score 3):

***Simplest method:***

(1.) Remove (undock) the current icon from Dash.

(2.) Use Unity to find this application (firefox).

(3.) Drag icon to Unity panel, then *right-click* on icon and select 'Lock to Launcher'.

---

***Assuming that doesn't work ..***

There should be a file **firefox.desktop** located in:

**/usr/share/applications/**

This should start with: (simplified for clarity)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Firefox Web Browser
Comment=Browse the World Wide Web
GenericName=Web Browser
Exec=firefox %u
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Icon=firefox
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Network;WebBrowser;
  :
```

Also delete any customised copy of **firefox.desktop** you find in:

**~/.local/share/applications/**

Answer (score 0):

In my case this behavior was caused by a Firefox shortcut on the desktop, and I just needed to remove it and re-add Firefox to the launcher. More details here:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2081710&p=12718813#post12718813