# Firefox developer desktop icon is missing

Tags: firefox, 17.10, icons

When I open Firefox from the launcher there is no icon.

[image: blank paper icon in dash]

When I run firefox from the terminal the icon appears. So far I have tried [Unity launcher uses generic icon for Firefox in Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/303929/unity-launcher-uses-generic-icon-for-firefox-in-ubuntu-12-04), but the issue still remains.

This is my firefox_dev.desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Firefox Developer Edition
GenericName=Web Browser
Exec=/opt/firefox/firefox
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/firefox/browser/icons/mozicon128.png
Type=Application
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;Favorites;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml_xml;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;x-scheme-handler/ftp;
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=NewWindow;NewIncognito
```

I have tried uninstalling and then installing again, but the issue is still the same.

Answer (score 3):

Same here, my FF developer edition icon is transparent since 17.10.

[SOLVED] I sorted out that by replacing the line

```
Icon=/home/YOU_USER_NAME/.local/share/umake/web/firefox-dev/browser/icons/mozicon128.png
```

by

```
Icon=/home/YOU_USER_NAME/.local/share/umake/web/firefox-dev/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
```

In my case I installed it with `umake`. In your case have a look at `/opt/firefox/browser` and find the equivalent icon.

Comment: Fresh 18.04 installed and this was the location for me ./firefox-dev/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png