# Lauch Firefox Developer Edition using command-line

Tags: command-line, firefox, 18.04

**Context**
On 18.04, firefox came preinstalled. On top of that, I installed Firefox Developer Edition. The latter is set as my default web-browser.

I don't use regular firefox at all, but I don't want to remove it as I fear it might brake something somewhere.

**Problem**
When I run `firefox` in my CLI, a new instance of regular-firefox is started.

**Question**
How to open Firefox Developer Edition using command line?

Comment: Then try `/opt/firefox_dev/firefox`. Also how did you install it actually? (the location of the executable depends on that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted by [pomsky](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049626/lauch-firefox-developer-edition-using-command-line?noredirect=1#comment1713634_1049626), the path of the executable file is `/opt/firefox_dev/firefox`. 
I then just had to [create a personalized bash alias](https://askubuntu.com/q/17536/498358) (e.g., `alias ff-dev='/opt/firefox_dev/firefox'`).

---

<sub>Note that this problem may be due to the fact I installed Firefox Web Developer from an archive (downloaded on [Mozilla's website](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/)). So I then needed to  to manually create the `firefox_dev.desktop` file — see [Firefox developer desktop icon is missing](https://askubuntu.com/q/1004496/498358) and [Firefox developer edition icon duplication in Gnome shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1004496/firefox-developer-desktop-icon-is-missing/1004930#1004930).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

In my case (Ubuntu 18.04):
`firefox` launches regular firefox
`firefox-developer`  launches firefox dev edition